# How to Validate form by using OnChange Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onchange

I am trying to do an extra check on a form using OnChange so an alert box appears if the text if equal to a specific value BEFORE the form is submitted. If i remove the If value then the alert box WILL appear but its not coming up if the field is set to 'No Longer Required'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
function extracheck(s) {

if (s.value == "No Longer Required"){
alert("message here");
}
}

/*]]>*/
</script>

 <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="returnprocess.asp" onSubmit="return     validateForm(this)">
  <select name="Reason1" class="textfieldmedium" id="Reason1" onchange="extracheck(this)">
                        <option selected="selected">Reason for Return</option>
                       <option>No Longer Required</option>
                        <option>Duplicated Order</option>
                        <option>Choice of Two</option>
                        <option>Incorrectly Supplied</option>
                        <option>Incorrect for Application</option>
                        <option>Incorrectly Packaged</option>
                        <option>Late Delivery</option>
                        <option>Incorrectly Picked</option>
                        <option>Never Ordered</option>
                        <option>Surcharge Unit</option>
                        <option>Damaged</option>
                        <option>Poor Fitment</option>
                          </select>
      </form>
```

Why isnt the alert box coming up when there is an IF statement ?

Comment: Looks fine to me [Take a look](http://jsbin.com/lotebiho/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Looks fine to me as well http://jsfiddle.net/o802e6mq/

Comment: I think there are a few issues with onchange in forms for some of the older browsers. I think using the JQuery onchange function might be a better solution.

Comment: I dont think that is a valid solution Konstantin. Forms have been used fine without jquery and unless hes already using jquery which it doesnt seem like there is no reason to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
function extracheck(s) {
    var e = document.getElementById("Reason1");
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value == "No Longer Required") {
        alert("message here");
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/lotebiho/1/

Comment: What's the point of copy-pasting my example from the comments above?

Comment: Actually, i first wrote in http://jsfiddle.net/fsp2wv1r/, but didn't case to save it as I posted it.  Relax dude.

Answer (score -1):

Alert is coming because function is executing every time and not on selection

try this,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Reason1").select(function() {
            if ($(".textfieldmedium").val() == "No Longer Required") {
                alert("Message here");
            }
        )};
    )};
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you even ran the code. The alert does not come every time.